# Why can't I use a pasted value inside a formula in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I've copied some credit card purchase info into an excel table as shown below:

[image]

The pasted values are located in columns `A` to `E`.

As you can see, I have the formula `SUM(E43:E51)` on cell `I44`. Why is it not working? On cell `I45` i have formula `SUM(G43:G51)` (**typed by hand**) and this time it works.

What do I have to do to fix the formula with the pasted data?

Comment: You have *text-that-looks-like-numbers*.

Comment: I selected the text, tried to change from GENERAL to NUMBER and to CURRENCY and it doesn't help... how can I solve it?

Comment: In a new cell, put `1`. Then copy that cell, select `E43:E51`, and paste special > multiply.

Comment: It doesn't affect the pasted values... (I've tried doing that putting a `2` instead of `1` and it only works on the typed values, not on the pasted.

Comment: Click on A43.  copy the entirety of what is in the formula bar and paste it here.  My guess is that all the data is in column A.

Comment: @ScottCraner content of `A43` is `25/11` (date of the purchase)

Comment: Try this: in an empty cell put `=--Trim(Clean(E43)` and tell me what you get.

Comment: I see commas in your numbers where you'd expect decimals. Excel is likely going to see that as text no matter what you do. Try changing the commas to decimals or removed them completely.

Comment: @ScottCraner I get `#VALUE!`, if i remove the  `--` before the `Trim` I get `500,00`

Comment: @Bigtree That is a local setting. If you look at the output of the formula they use , as the decimal separator. Many countries have their numbers that way.

Comment: @vmp Then the "numbers" are definitely saved as text and there is an unseen character that is keeping Excel from recognizing it as a number.  You will need to go in the cell and find the unseen character and delete it.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks! there was an empty space at the end... Do you know any practical way of removing that extra space at the end for the whole column?

Comment: If trim did not fix it then it is a non breaking space: `=--TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(E43,CHAR(160),"")))` put that in an empty cell and copy down.

Comment: It worked, thanks so much!